# Como enviar correos con un store procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

Necesito enviar un correo todos los días que informe de procesos aprobados, pero que también identifique el correo receptor. Es un sistema de contratos, un usuario genera una solicitud de personal y cuando este es aprobado se debe enviar un email al correo del usuario solicitante. Hasta el momento tengo algo pero envía el correo la cantidad de veces que itera la consulta a una tabla, adjunto código del SP...

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[SP030_RH_EnviaEmailAprobados]

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @TablaHtml NVARCHAR(MAX);
Declare @Mail as Varchar(50)
DECLARE CURSORMAIL CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR

SELECT u.MailUsuario from TB030_RH_Postulante post inner join TB030_RH_ProcesoBusqueda pbus on post.IdProceso = pbus.IdProceso
inner join TB030_RH_SolicitudPersonal sper on sper.IdSolicitud = pbus.IdSolicitud inner join TB030_GB_Usuario u on u.CodUsuario
= sper.CodUsuarioSol  inner join TB030_RH_CargoPersonal cper on cper.CodCargo = sper.CodCargo where post.EstadoPostulante = 1 FOR READ ONLY;

OPEN CURSORMAIL;
FETCH CURSORMAIL INTO @Mail;

while   @@fetch_status = 0
begin

SET @TablaHtml =
N'<H1>Sistema de gestión de contratos</H1>'+
N'Este correo se genera de forma automática por favor no responda.'+
N'<table border ="1">'+
N'<tr><th>Nombre</th><th>Apellido</th><th>Correo</th><th>Teléfono</th><th>Descripción cargo</><th>Correo solicitante</>'+
CAST ((SELECT td= post.Nombre, '',
td = post.Apellido,'',
td = post.Correo,'',
td = post.Telefono,'',
td = cper.DesCargo,'',
td = u.MailUsuario,''

from TB030_RH_Postulante post inner join TB030_RH_ProcesoBusqueda pbus on post.IdProceso = pbus.IdProceso
inner join TB030_RH_SolicitudPersonal sper on sper.IdSolicitud = pbus.IdSolicitud inner join TB030_GB_Usuario u on u.CodUsuario
= sper.CodUsuarioSol  inner join TB030_RH_CargoPersonal cper on cper.CodCargo = sper.CodCargo where post.EstadoPostulante = 1 and u.MailUsuario = @Mail
FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE
) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
N'</table>';

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name='Alerta Aprobacion',
@recipients= @Mail,
@blind_copy_recipients = @Mail,
@subject = 'Alarma de entrevistados aprobados',
@body = @TablaHtml,
@body_format = 'HTML',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 0;

FETCH NEXT FROM CURSORMAIL INTO @Mail;
end

CLOSE CURSORMAIL;
DEALLOCATE CURSORMAIL;
END
```

Comment: Según entiendo, el problema es que el correo se envía demasiadas veces. ¿Cuánto es demasiado? Se va a ejecutar por cada linea que regrese el SELECT que crea al cursor. Corrige ese SELECT y se acaba el problema.

Comment: Cual de los 2 select?

Comment: Sólo hay uno que declara el cursor.

Comment: Necesito identificar el mail del usuario solicitante por eso la consulta...

Comment: Lo envía la cantidad de veces que itera la consulta porque está dentro de un `while`. ¿Qué es lo que quieres lograr, si no es eso?

Answer (score -1):

Puedes utilizar sp_send_mail de la siguiente forma:

```
USE msdb
GO

EXEC sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name='Gmail', --Este es el perfil que se configuro previamente,
@recipients='leur0985@gmail.com', --El correo al cual se le enviará
@subject='Mensaje de Prueba', --El asunto del correo
@body='Este es un correo de prueba enviado desde SQL SERVER' --El cuerpo del correo.
```

Previamente se debió configurar un perfil para poder enviar un correo. Te dejo la liga:

https://www.respuestasit.com.mx/2020/05/configurar-correo-de-gmail-y-outlook-en.html

Una vez configurado el perfil, puedes seguir este enlance para mayor información

https://www.respuestasit.com.mx/2020/05/enviar-mail-desde-sql-server.html